# React TypeScript: How to type set Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

Currently I have to do the following:

```js
interface MyCompProps {
    someAttr: number
}
```

I want to use `aria-`, and then I have to list upfront all `aria-*` I need. Furthermore, I can't set a simple `className` on the component. How can I avoid this, i.e. allow normal HTML attributes on component? Or is it a bad practice? I'm skimming the Advanced Guides on reactjs website and nowhere mention that this is a bad practice, so I think it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that all aria-* HTML attributes are fully supported in JSX. Whereas most DOM properties and attributes in React are camelCased, these attributes should be hyphen-cased (also known as kebab-case, lisp-case, etc) as they are in plain HTML

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#wai-aria)